# Moving group of nodes together in D3 force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I need help figuring out how to drag and drop a group of nodes based on a hull group.

Specifically,

- I can drag and drop the hull, which move the nodes and links along with it. Basically everything in the group moves together, which is what I'm looking for.
- If I drag and drop nodes and I don't move the hulls, the drag behaviour for nodes works as expected.
- If I drag and drop a hull and then try to drag and drop nodes, the drag and drop behaviour does not work as expected for nodes.

**Update :** 
I finally figured out the the drag and drop behavior on hulls and nodes. I posted a working fiddle here. I hope it is useful to others in the future.

http://jsfiddle.net/mbgw2ooc/2/

The method I am having trouble with is below :

```
Vis.prototype.moveNodeGroup = function(iGroup, iPath){
    var path = d3.select(iPath);
    var nodes = path.data()[0].values;

    var translate = d3.transform(iPath.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
    var dx = d3.event.dx + translate[0];
    var dy = d3.event.dy + translate[1];

    path.attr("transform", "translate(" + dx + "," + dy + ")");


    //How to move the hulls, nodes and links permanently so the update
    //redraws properly 

};
```

Thank you in advance for the push in the right direction.

Rene

Comment: not an answer to your specific problem but have you seen [webcola](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/)?

Comment: Thank you I will have a look but I was really hoping to resolved the issue as most of my code is written and I'm on  tight deadline.

Comment: I had a look at webcola. It's an impressive library and great that it works with D3 and Cytoscape. However, I need to support over 100 nodes in my use case.